# Convert adb screencap raw to png

Tags: python, numpy, adb

I'm trying to avoid using `screencap -p` because it is at least 3 times slower than output `raw`. But I am having difficulties in converting raw into png.

```
import subprocess
import cv2
import numpy as np

output = subprocess.check_output(f'src\\adb\\adb -s {serial} shell screencap')
array = np.frombuffer(output[12:], np.uint8).reshape(720, 1280, 4)
image = cv2.cvtColor(array, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)
```

I got this exception：

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
cannot reshape array of size 3691368 into shape (720,1280,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing the question, I read the exception again and realised it must be some formatting issues, such as `\r\n` instead of `\n`, causing the array size to be that weird number.

The solution is as simple as:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(f'src\\adb\\adb -s {serial} shell screencap').replace(b'\r\n', b'\n')
```

Hope this helps others.